# multiple wordpress custom post meta values

Tags: wordpress, post, field, meta

I'm pretty hopeless at PHP, so I figured I'd ask for a bit of help!

I'm using WordPress as a CMS for a music agency site at [daviesmusic.com](http://daviesmusic.com) and have lots of extra information for the various artists via custom fields. So far, I've just retrieved the custom field values one by one, like so:

```
<?php
    //audio title
    $audio_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'audio_name', true);
    if ($audio_title) :
?>

    <p><?php echo $audio_title; ?></p>
```

This works fine, only I have lots of custom fields that all require different outputs. I have for instance a photo for the artist, an audio file, the title of the audio file and some notes about the audio file, like so:

```
    <?php
    //profile image
    $profile_pic = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'profileimage', true);
    if($profile_pic) :
?>

    <img class="post-thumb-single" src="<?php bloginfo('template_directory'); ?>/timthumb.php?src=<?php echo $profile_pic; ?>&a=t&h=278&w=278&zc=1" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />

<?php   
    endif;
    //photographer
    $photographer = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'photographer', true);
    if($photographer) :
?>

    <p id="photographer">Photographer: <b><?php echo $photographer; ?></b></p>

<?php
    endif;
    //audio title
    $audio_title = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'audio_title', true);
    if ($audio_title) :
?>

    <h4 class="nsmb">Audio files</h4>

    <p><?php echo $audio_title; ?></p>

<?php
    //audio file
    $audio = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'audiofile', true);
    if ($audio) :
?>


<p class="audio" id="audioplayer_1">Sorry, there was a problem loading the file.</p>
<script>AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer_1", {soundFile: "<?php echo $audio; ?>"});</script>


  <?php
    $audio_credits_1 = get_post_meta($post->ID, 'audio_credits_1', true);
    if ($audio_credits_1) :
  ?>

    <p class="audio_cred"><?php echo $audio_credits_1; ?></p>

    <?php
        endif; endif; endif;
    ?>
```

Lots of code. I'm sure there must be a more efficient way to retrieve the values! Any ideas?!

Cheers

Comment: Wrap it up into a function that accepts an array of keys and outputs the appropriate HTML depending on the key? Want an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take this example from [here](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_custom):

```
$custom_fields = get_post_custom(72);
$my_custom_field = $custom_fields['my_custom_field'];
foreach ( $my_custom_field as $key => $value ){
    echo $key . " => " . $value . "<br />";
}
```

This will cycle through all specified custom values for the post (id #72 in this example, you can get yours using `$post->ID` as you have in your code). You can use `$key` to print the field name, and `$value` to print the value of that field. You can get more granular with how they're displayed using an `if elseif else` statement or a [`switch`](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: Sorry it's taken me 6 months to reply! Thanks for your answer!